# TYPO3 Preview not working - wrong URL

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have problem with TYPO3 Previews. When i try to preview a page I get a 404 Error because the URL is wrong. Instead of

`mydomain.com/typo3subfolder/index.php?id=10`

the PreviewURL is

`mydomain.com/typo3subfolder:2/index.php?id=10`

I set the domain as `BaseUrl` and checked the Installtool but i cant find the error. 
Typo3 Version is 6.1.3. But it also didn't work with 6.0

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean the Web>View Preview?

The common way to handle this issue would be through page tsconfig;
in particular:

```
TCEMAIN.previewDomain = https://www.example.com/[subfolder]
```

This value also respects a given subfolder.

Comment: thanks, this works - however I wonder why Typo3 is confused about the subfolder. Seem to be a bug or a config problem.

Answer (score 1):

It will not depend on the Version of TYPO3.

Did you set an domain record? If there is a domain record, that domain is used for preview. If there are more than once, the first in listview will be used. Check if there is a domain record "mydomain.com/typo3subfolder:2/". If yes, delete it.

Perhaps you have an RewriteRule in your .htaccess which has an typo in it...?

If there are HTTP redirects, you should be able to detect them via 
firebug (Firefox Plugin). Open Network Tab ans set "permanent". So, check if any http redirect takes effect.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. There is no Domainrecord anywhere in my sitetree. I tried setting one. The effect is that the preview loads a bit longer but the URL-parameter is still persistent. 

There is only one http Request made :( Ill check the htaccess

Comment: disable all extensions, so you will see if it depends on one of them

Comment: No, doesnt help either :/ I only have installed: yag,tt_news,yag_tt_news,macina_search_box, templavoila